# Missing "NewLine" characters in data sent by arduino device

Tags: c#, string, arduino, processing, uwp

In my UWP app I'm reading data from a serial port. To this port I'm sending continuously data with an arduino device using `Serial.println("{text}");`. So I expected the receiving data looks like:

```
{text}\n\r{text}\n\r{text}\n\r{text}\n\r{text}\n\r{text}\n\r{text}\n\r...
```

But what I can read from the inputstream looks like:

```
{text}{text}{text}{text}{text}{text}{text}
```

In the receiving data there are no new line characters. I thought printLn() would send these characters or do I have to send them explicitly?

Comment: are you sending one `"{text}"` at a time with `prinln` command?

Comment: Might be totally uninteresting for you or maybe you're already using it, but have you take a look at Windows Remote Arduino library? It looks like you can avoid raw data reading whatsoever with it. [Here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/02/04/what-is-windows-remote-arduino-and-what-can-it-do/) is more info.

Comment: @AbdurRahim Yes one "{text}" at a time and then again and again..

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin I will check it. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/) and [the Serial source code](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/java/libraries/serial/src/processing/serial/Serial.java), I don't see a `Serial.println()` function. Are you sure that's what function you're calling?

Comment: @KevinWorkman https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. It is a known issue with the analog input. You have to set a delay in between reads for stability. I did that, but I have two analog reads. After I set also a delay behind the second analog reads everything works fine and all characters are sent.